# What is the source of the teaching that Hashem, unlike humanity, perceives time continuously?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, time

I recall once reading a passage that discussed divine perception of reality. The idea was something like this: Humans blink their eyes, and so do not see everything that happens in time. Hashem, however, sees what happens even during those eyeblinks and so has complete understanding.

I'm not certain this came from a religious source of any sort; it may have been words placed in the mouth of a character from some Jewish fiction. If anyone recognizes this description I'd greatly appreciate having my memory jogged.

Comment: Hashem is outside of time so I'm not sure I follow

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=f_kCQ5XnOFwC&pg=PT50&lpg=PT50&dq=human+blinking+god+sees+everything&source=bl&ots=Xqm8MI-HDS&sig=ACfU3U0u0Hx-M1hUVx4Ux9b1-Ov9S7iFZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ66Whl63zAhVjhuAKHRA3DugQ6AF6BAgFEAI

Comment: So if humans didn't blink they'd have the same perception as G-d? The character in that fiction must have been pretty dumb.

Comment: G-d is an all-encompassing, infinite Creator. To apply terms "understanding" or "perception" to an all-encompassing Creator is not logical. The term "understanding" requires three separate components: the one understanding, the subject of knowledge, and the knowledge itself. Because G-d is perfect, he contains all three within himself. Rambam discusses this in [Mishne Torah Yisodei Hatorah 2:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.2.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Comment: @Chatzkel This looks like what I might be remembering. I don't suppose you have any idea which of Potok's books it might have been?

Comment: @Tesvov I appreciate and agree with your answers (also that of robev). I'm not trying to evaluate the teaching, just trying to remember where I heard it. Looks like it may have been fictional anyway, not to be taken completely seriously.

Comment: @Larry Denenberg it looks like it is in his book called The Chosen

Comment: @robev ''''Hashem is outside of time so I'm not sure I follow""" I think that's better to say, time is inside of Hashem, so He doesn't undergo the time'

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam in the beginning of the Yad says in the first chapter of הלכות יסודי התורה

> **יא** וְכֵיוָן שֶׁנִּתְבָּרֵר שֶׁאֵינוֹ גּוּף וּגְוִיָּה יִתְבָּרֵר שֶׁלֹּא יֶאֱרַע לוֹ אֶחָד מִמְּאֹרְעוֹת הַגּוּפוֹת. לֹא חִבּוּר וְלֹא פֵּרוּד. לֹא מָקוֹם וְלֹא מִדָּה. לֹא עֲלִיָּה וְלֹא יְרִידָה. וְלֹא יָמִין וְלֹא שְׂמֹאל. וְלֹא פָּנִים וְלֹא אָחוֹר. וְלֹא יְשִׁיבָה וְלֹא עֲמִידָה. **וְאֵינוֹ מָצוּי בִּזְמַן** עַד שֶׁיִּהְיֶה לוֹ רֵאשִׁית וְאַחֲרִית וּמִנְיַן שָׁנִים. ‏

Basically, time is one of Hashem's creations, and therefore He's *above time*. He has no start, no end or aging concept, as these are all part of His creation called *time*.

We probably cannot understand this fully, but it's conceivable that Hashem sees all of *time* as a long continuum.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're referring to this?

Hashem's name YKWK has a basic meaning or kawana, meditation, and that is

> היה הוה ויהיה

Was, is, and will be.

This is printed in many Sefardic siddurim such as Avodat Hashem